# express handlebars #each rendering of mongodb find() returns [object][object]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, handlebars.js

I'm having an issue where my template is not rendering anything sent back from my mongodb database.

I have the following route and template:

```
// Removing items page 
// --------------------------------------------------
router.post('/removeItems', (req, res) => {
   res.render('removeItems', {prods: crudOps.getProducts(res)})

});
```

```
<form action="/admin/removeItems" method="POST">
  <label for="item">ID</label>
        <input type="text" class = "form-control" name = "id" is= "id" >
</form>


<div>
    {{prods}}
</div>

<div class="container">
    {{#each prods}}
        <div class="form-group">
            <form action="/admin/removeItems" method="POST">
            <p>{{prods.name}}</p>
            <img height='70px' width='70px'>{{prods.file}}</img>
            <p>{{prods.value}}</p>
            <p>{{prods.desc}}</p>
            <p>{{prods._id}}</p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" class = "form-control">Remove</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

my function is exported from a file meant to handle crud operations

```
const getProducts = function(res){
  MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', (err, client) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    let db = client.db('account-app');
    let products = db.collection('products');
    let users = db.collection('users');


       products.find().toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
        return result
      })
      client.close()
  })
}
```

my assumption is that whatever is returned by my function can be used by my template inside the object passed to res.render. Am I perhaps missing some key for indexing? or am I mishandling my mongo call? I am able to console.log the data coming back.

all my documents inside my products collection have the following structure:

the file attribute is an image file.

```
name:"dd"
file:Binary('/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAYEBQYFBAYGBQYHBwYIChAKCgkJChQODwwQFxQYGBcUFhYaHSUfGhsjHBYICwgIyYn...', 0)
value:"dd"
desc:"dd
```

this is my first time using handlebars but everything looks fine to me, I'm not sure what's missing?

Comment: the are obects, so u have to try access the keys, like `{prods.name}`

Comment: I’m accessing the keys in the handlebars template. Is that what you are referring to?